# pending transaction blocked on a local private node

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, pending-transactions

Geth v1.6.1-stable on linux

i have initialized my data localy with :

```
geth --datadir "data" init "genesis.json"
```

then i run geth to launch local node with very low gasPrice

```
geth --datadir "data" --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --mine --minerthreads 8 --unlock 0,1 --gasprice 10 console 2>console.log
```

i want to access this node through web3js from a local firefox running remix to compile a very simple smartcontract

i have 2 accounts with ether
but anytime i execute a function from my smartcontract 
operations keep being locked "pending" 
they are never processed by the node..

What is wrong with this node ?
all accounts are local, unlocked ..

Thanks by advance if you have any idea ..

Vinz

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check if

eth.mining 
true

anyway run
miner.stop()
miner.start(1)

check logs of geth (--verbosity 5)

and wait to see "Sealed block" or something like that

another option can be to recreate a genesis file with less difficulty